# detect if string contains pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

How to detect if string contains pattern with JavaScript:

```
1. input="[Lorem]foo";
2. input="[ ]";
3. input="[ipsum]foo";
4. input="[dolor]foo1";
5. input="[sit  ]foo2";
6. input="[ amet]foo3";
7. input="amet]foo3";
...
```

Script should process `input` in this way:

```
1. string1='Lorem'; string2="foo";
2. do nothing;
3. string1='ipsum'; string2="foo";
4. string1='dolor'; string2="foo1";
5. do nothing;
6. do nothing;
7. do nothing;
...
```

---

This would be a part of script...

```
input  = "[asd]qwe";
input2 = "qwe";

processit(input);
processit(input2);

function processit(e){

   if(..???..){
      alert(string1);
      alert(string2);
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }

}
```

Thank you for your time.

---

EDIT:
Solution must be cross-browser

IE7 +

Firefox 3.6+

Chrome 7+
...

Comment: Kind of a hard to see what seems to be the problem! If you need info about Regular expression - [MDN RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and a [site dedicated to RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jsbin code](http://jsbin.com/ipacib/2/edit)

This regex should achieve the result: `/\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/`

Comment: Those `[^\s]` constructs shouldn't be there.  You're already telling it to match alphanumerics and nothing else with `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`; there's no need to tell it *not* to match whitespace.  Also, you're requiring the first string to be at least three characters long, and you're dropping the last character because the second `[^\s]` is outside the capturing group.

Comment: `\w` will work in place of each `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - it is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Also, as you want to match only the whole string, the regex should start with `^` and end with `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of how `split()` works with capturing groups.

```
var pieces = str.split(/\[(\w+?)\]/);
```

You may get some empty string values. You can remove them with...

```
pieces.filter(function(piece) { return piece; });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJzZ7/).

Comment: It DOES NOT work in Internet Explorer. `Webpage error details Message: Object doesn't support this property or method` Any suggestions?

Comment: @enloz You can [shim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) `split()` to get it to work in IE.

Comment: I would imagine that `pieces.filter` is the piece unsupported by IE.

Comment: @EricWendelin: `filter` is unsupported in IE <= 8. IE 9 does support it.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual requirements are unclear, so I'm guessing. The following will allow only non-empty alphanumeric-plus-underscore-only strings inside and after the brackets, and tries to match the whole string rather than multiple occurrences in a longer string.

```
var input = "[Lorem]foo";
var string1, string2;
var result = /^\[(\w+)\](\w+)$/i.exec(input);
if (result) {
    string1 = result[1];
    string2 = result[2];
}
alert(string1 + ", " + string2);
```